# Get the latest event logs

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, event-viewer

I'm trying to find out how much data is generated in logs the last 24 hours on my server.

The thought was to summarize the file sizes found with this command:

```
Get-WinEvent -ListLog * | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt ((Get-Date) - (New-TimeSpan -Day 1))} | Format-List -Property LogName, FileSize, LastWriteTime
```

The problem with this is that I seemingly only get the last time it wrote to file at C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs, and not the ones that are seemingly in the memory. I'm looking for everything up to the second the script is run!

Can you help me with a better method?

Comment: Much data what? Number of events? Log size?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I meant data size

Answer (score 3):

You will need to read the events out of the logs to do that:

```
Get-EventLog -ListLog | Foreach {
    $_ | Get-WinEvent { ... processs the events ... }}
```

Unfortunately there is not a `Size` property on the EventLogRecord objects.  There is ToXml() method that you could use and then get the length of generated XML.  That is rather crude though.  Another way would be to add up the size of all the properties. Since the object structure is fixed, you could pre-compute the size of properties like bool, int, guid.  However you would need to determine the length of strings at runtime.